# Puma crashes with Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) when use fastimage gem on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, puma

I decided to try to use Windows as a development platform for ruby. When I use this code: `<%= FastImage.size('https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/frontdoor/creative/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg') %>`, server crashes with this message: `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. But the same code works perfectly in rails console. Any ideas of how can I make this code work? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

This would suggest that the binary/native components in your puma gem were not built properly to be compatible with your system.  I don't know anything about building puma on Windows, but I'd direct your attention there.